# Self-Study: Convolution Sum Uniform RV, Bounds Of Integration

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, convolution, uniform-distribution, density-function

I am trying to solve a problem which consists of:

$X_1, X_2 \overset{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim} U([{\mu -1, \mu + 1}])$. Find the density of $Y=X_1+X_2$.

I have read the related questions to this topic, but it still does not help me find a solution. Here is what I have tried so far:

Let: 
$$y = x_1 + x_2 \Rightarrow y - x_1 = x_2$$

$$f_{X_1}(x_1) = {1 \over 2} = f_{X_2}(x_2) \rightarrow \int_{\mu -1}^{\mu+1}{1\over 2}dx_1 = {1\over 2}x_1 \bigg|_{\mu -1}^{\mu+1} = {1\over 2}(\mu + 1 - \mu - 1) = {2\over 2} = 1$$

Thus the joint density is:

$$f_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) = {1\over 2}{1\over 2} = {1\over 4}$$

Now substituting $x_2 = y - x_1$:

$$f_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, y - x_1) = {1\over 2}{1\over 2} = {1\over 4}$$

and to get the marginal distribution of $y$:

$$f_{Y}(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y}(y - x_1)f_{X_1}(x_1)dx_1 $$

Now comes the part where I have difficulties. The bounds of $y = x_1 + x_2$ are:

$$2\mu-2 \lt y \lt 2\mu +2$$

and the bounds for $x_1$ are:

$$\mu-1 \lt x_1 \lt \mu +1$$

So I have to split the bounds of $y$ into three parts:

$$
\begin{cases}
2\mu-2 + (\mu+1) \lt y,& \text{ for } 2\mu -2 \lt  y \lt \mu-1 \\
\mu - 1 \lt y,&  \text{ for } \mu -1 \lt y \lt \mu+1 \\
y - (\mu+1)\lt \mu+1, &  \text{ for } \mu +1 \lt y \lt 2\mu+2
\end{cases}
$$

which would result in:

$$
f_{Y}(y) = 
\begin{cases}
\int_{2\mu-2 + (\mu+1)}^{y} {1\over 2} dx_1 \\
\int_{\mu - 1}^{y} {1\over 2} dx_1\\
\int_{y - \mu+1}^{\mu+1} {1\over 2} dx_1
\end{cases}
$$

Is that correct?

Comment: I edited your question to make more sense, but looks like your convolution formula is messed up.

Comment: I just cant really figure out how to obtain the intervals, and to integrate from to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you an easier (In my opinion) way to get the result.

$X_1$ and $X_2$ can be interpreted as two copies of Lebesgue measure multiplied by an opportune costant (In this case $\frac{1}{2}$) in $[\mu-1,\mu+1]$.

Then, using the product of measure ($X_1$ and $X_2$ are indipendet) you can easly get that $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in A, X_2 \in B)=\mathscr{L^1}(A)\mathscr{L^1}(B)$ where $\mathscr{L}^1(A)=\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in A)$ for any measurable set of $[\mu-1,\mu+1]$ and the same for $\mathscr{L^1}(B)$.

Then $F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2 \leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq y - X_2)$ can easly get computing the area of $\{(t,h) \in \mathbb{R}^2:h \leq y-t\} \cap [\mu-1,\mu+1] \times [\mu-1,\mu+1]$ which is easy because there are only two possible figure: a triangle and a trapeze. Then is it sufficient to derivate (where it is possible) the function $F_Y(y)$.

Comment: thank for the answer, I would totaly accept it, however part of the exercise is to understand how to find the bounds of integration.

Comment: Okay, I understand you. I am sorry if my answer does not help you. I wrote this answer because I think that the way I chose could help you to see graphically the bounds you are searching for. In fact those bounds are exactly the one that you find when you consider the area of  this figure $\{(t,h) \in \mathbb{R}^2:h \leq y-t\} \cap [\mu-1,\mu+1] \times [\mu-1,\mu+1]$ in the plane.

Comment: Alright I appreciate it, no one else is answering anyway, so I hope you get some additional points. i'll upvote your question. I am sure it's correct anyway.